# Is Multi language support possible in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Am creating a website.Is support of other languages apart from English possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can either translate your content with the locale module, which is a part of Drupal core, or you can use the [internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module to create a multi lingual Drupal site.

Comment: Thanks but where can i find the Internationalization module?

Comment: @Angel Try clicking the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you're talking about the back end language or multi language output of pages. In the second case Google helps: [Drupal > Locale](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/locale)
I'm sure the first is provided, too.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is a lot of translation modules, etc. It can even translate on the fly if you;re using some of the more popular languages.